# RAVPower USB Battery Pack as Power Source

Tags: power-supply, usb-power, battery

I know there have been several questions about USB battery packs posted throughout Raspberry Pi forums across the internet and I have read as many as I could find but I still feel like I don't have a clear answer to this question.

I know that powering a Raspberry Pi 3 through a USB battery pack is possible if it constantly outputs 5V and provides sufficient amperage to the Pi and its peripherals. Has anyone found a USB battery pack that is able to fulfil these requirements? The goal is to be able to power a Raspberry Pi 3, a Waveshare 3.2in touch screen, and a USB camera solely through the USB battery pack. I want to be able to start my video recording program and then leave the Pi alone until either the SD card is full or the battery is empty. I am conservatively estimating that this set up will draw about 1325 mA. I have been looking at RAVPower USB battery packs, specifically the RAVPower 16750 mAh and the RAVPower 12000 mAh. If I did my calculations correctly, I am estimating that they would give me around 9 hours and 6 hours respectively. Does anyone have any experience with these battery packs that could provide some input on if they would work for my project or not?

Thank you for any and all feedback.

Comment: USB powerbanks, which are intended for *recharging other batteries, usually < 5V,* are probably mostly insufficient for the Pi 3.  You may get lucky, and you can likely get away with it at least some of the time, but no one can promise you anything.  Put another way, your assumptions here are highly optimistic and subject to some fine print ;)

Comment: Max current and capacity are two separate ratings: having 16750 mAh does not guarantee you will get 1325 mA. Also, measuring the current your RPi consumes is much more reliable than estimating it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to that other question. Lots of good information there. I looked into the Adafruit Powerboost 1000 and it satisfies the voltage requirement of the Raspberry Pi 3 but it doesn't look like it will provide sufficient amps. Are there any on the market that could output 2A instead of 1A that you know of?